# How to remove image tag if no image is loaded at the time of page creating

Tags: jquery, css, image

```
$image ='< img src="http://xyz.com/'.$add_image4.'" class="magnify" alt="/>';
```

& if `$add_image4` is empty,blank image still shows how do I remove it?

Comment: Explain your scenario better.If you want people to pun effort in an answer,put some effort in your question .

Comment: You can try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/q3L7N/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
<img src="http://theglenbot.com/a-broken-image.jpg" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />
```

[Ths post](http://theglenbot.com/html-image-tag-onerror-attribute/) might help you.

Comment: thats nice!!! but if you read the post included its not valid code so you could better use the jquery way also mentioned in the post.

Comment: Your always welcome. Kindly consider it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $("img.magnify").on('error', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

As written, all img nodes with `class="magnify"` will be removed if they fail to load.

The "img.magnify" selector can be adjusted to address more/less/different img nodes as required.

Comment: be aware on() is new since jquery 1.7